# save table structure to variable after 2nd row?

Tags: jquery

if in html table have 5 row, 1 and 2 are safe, 3,4,5 must be saved as html structure to a variable. like this

```
var after2ndContent= '<tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>5</td></tr>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a continuation of your previous post, you can use this

```
var elemRemoved = $("#tbl1 tr:gt(1)").detach();
var removedContents = $("<div />").append(elemRem).remove().html();
alert ( removedContents );
```

Comment: thanks, it works great. is possible to get live html content?
because in <td> tags has <input type="text" />. alert ( removedContents ); return    "<tr bgcolor="#33ff66"><td><input id="txt91" type="text"></td><input id="txt92" type="text"></tr>". without input values. it will be very nice, if i can get with input values...

Answer (score 1):

As jQuery does not have an outerHTML function, it's a bit tricky:

```
$('<table>').append($('tr:gt(1)').clone()).remove().html();
```

That is:

- Create a dummy table element
- Append the rows after the second row (`gt()` is zero-indexed)
- Get the contents of this table (including the `<tr>` tags) and remove the element

If you simply used `$('tr:gr(1)').html()`, you'd probably just get the contents of the first `<tr>`.

Comment: sorry, but i have some problem. 
var after2ndContent=$('#dictTable').append($('tr:gt(1)').clone()).remove().html();
alert(after2ndContent) it shows full html content of page